# how to sort String list with multiple objects by descending order

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Ive got a list which contains data separated by a comma.
Its part of a C# ASP.net project.
so the data in my list looks like this:

```
10323323,102,99-11
13223,101,00-10
23234323223,178,00-99
```

I want to re-arrange the list so that the value in the middle arranges the items in the lost in descending order so id end up with a list that looks like.

```
13223,101,00-10    
10323323,102,99-11
23234323223,178,00-99
```

Comment: the value on the middle is a millilitre value and the rest are RFID tag numbers.

Comment: .sortBy(r -> r[1]) ?

Comment: does each string always have 3 values?

Comment: hello, yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings are always 3 values comma-separated, and the middle value is a string representation of an `integer`, something like this should do the job:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "10323323,102,99-11",
    "13223,101,00-10",
    "23234323223,178,00-99"
};

list = list.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(',')[1])).ToList();
```

Comment: Should be corrected in terms of the second value is integer.

Comment: excellent, that worked perfectly. i was messing around for ages before you posted the answer Arthur Rey. Thanks